# Javascript plugin for automatic rotation of images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

need to let the images disappear and reappear like here (footer at) http://www.guiltypeople.nl/het-bureau/.

Each logo, disappear slowly, and reappear on a different place. Could you help me find a Javascript plugin or something to do this?

thanks

Comment: You could do it like how they are. Stack multiple images on top of each other, then randomly animate other images to the front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:** To overlap the images you must make a trick with `position: absolute` or play a bit with `background`. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782601/how-can-we-overlap-two-images-using-css-style), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19314672/how-can-i-overlay-multiple-images-using-html-css-or-javascript-without-using-po) and [here](http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/832132-4-common-methods-overlap-2-images-css-any-more-method-orelse-use-program).

- TIP: If the position it's random and not a loop, you must implement a function which changes location of background hidden object's with `jquery` or `javascript`.

**Second:** When you have the images overlapped, you must make the transition effect. For this you must use a loop and the [alpha css property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp).

- In your original question you asked also for rotations and other FX, for this you don't need a plugin, check [transforming with css](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp).

Example of changin `alpha` property in plain `javascript`:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 100;){
    var element = document.getElementById('id');
    element.style.opacity = i * 0.1;
    element.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity=' + i + ')'; // IE fallback
    i = i + 10;
}
```

You can use the iterations to make rotation also, or use less `i` increment to perform each action when `mod` condition is true, imagine you want to rotate 90 degrees 4 times and make image disapear in 10 steps:

```
i = i + 5; // allows 20 iterations

if (i % 25 == 0) // if you want 4 rotation steps

if (i % 10 == 0) // if you want 10 alpha modifications
```

Comment: jordi, you are right when you are rotating each image, but i meant really let the image disappear, and reappear on a different position...(no rotating it 7 degrees or something)

Comment: @Enzo ... reedited the answer... if you workaround a bit is not hard to do what you want

Comment: OKay thanks I sent this to the dev's thanks!